# How to calculate rank of the player with most money?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a leaderboard which is built by joining two different databases, the most important is the wallet column which is what I'll use to rank the players. I need to add a column ranked from the player with most money to least amount of money. What is the best way to do this?

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM darkrp_player inner join playerinformation on (darkrp_player.uid = playerinformation.uid)");
```

Comment: `echo $rank++;` ?

Comment: get the info from the database using `ORDER BY` (see for more info on how to use ORDER BY here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html )

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to order by on your `wallet` column to short for showing **most money to least amount of money** of the user i.e `DESC` ordering. But if you want to get the **rank number** value of each user also apart from ordering you can do it this way with `ROW_NUMBER()` [window](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function

```
SELECT *, rank FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wallet DESC) as rank
  FROM darkrp_player INNER JOIN playerinformation ON (darkrp_player.uid = playerinformation.uid)
) t
```

**Expected Output:** on `$result` variable

```
id    other........columns      wallet rank
1111  xyz............abc         100    1 
2222  xyz............abc          90    2
3333  xyz............abc          80    3
```

Comment: this is cool. I just got it working so I'm going to move forward but thank you so much!

Comment: @gabriel0369 best of luck, but I still think windowing will make your code very less in this use case, you just need to use iterate the result and show on the table no fancy increment decrement and other stuff. **But the choice is yours**

Comment: Right! It does look a lot cleaner but I seriously don't care anymore at this point I'm just being quick about it lol. If I come across any problems I'll come back to this. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

alright these work! here's my code for anyone that might across something similar

```
 <table class="table" data-order='[[ 0, "asc" ]]'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Avatar</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Wallet</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("bla bla bla"); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM darkrp_player inner join playerinformation on (darkrp_player.uid = playerinformation.uid) ORDER BY wallet DESC");

$rank = 1;
 while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
?>
<?php
$steamid2 = $row['steamID'];    
$slice = substr($steamid2, strpos($steamid2, ":") + 1);    
$n = substr($slice, 0, 1);
$x = substr($slice, strpos($slice, ":") + 1);
$steamid64 = 76561197960265728 + 2 * $x + $n;
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=keykeykeykeykeyk&steamids='.$steamid64.'');
$parsed = json_decode($json);

?>
 <tr id="rank<?php echo $rank++; ?>">
<td><?php echo $rank - 1; ?></td>
<td><?php foreach($parsed->response->players as $player){
    echo "<a href=" . $player->profileurl . "><img src='" . $player->avatarmedium . "'></a>";
} ?></td>
<td><?php foreach($parsed->response->players as $player){
    echo "<a href=" . $player->profileurl . ">" . $player->personaname . "</a>";
} ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['salary']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['wallet']; ?></td>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(".table").DataTable();
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).